# Mechanism of multiple imputation?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-imputation

I am trying to understand the mechanism underline multiple imputation ideas. I am confusing on     creating multiple sets of estimates and then average them. For example:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(
x1=rnorm(100,10,2),
x2=rbinom(100,20,0.6))

y=rbinom(100,1,0.5)
#set missing values
ms<-sample(1:100,20)
y[ms]<-NA
df$y<-y

#predict NA

fit<-glm(y~x1+x2,data=df,family="binomial")
pred<-predict(fit,newdata=df[,c("x1","x2")],type="response")
df$yfit1<-with(df,ifelse(pred>=0.4,1,0))
    df$yimp1<-with(df,ifelse(is.na(y),yfit1,y))

         x1 x2  y yfit1 yimp1
1  8.879049 14  1     1     1
2  9.539645  8  0     1     0
3 13.117417 11 NA     1     1
4 10.141017 12  1     1     1
5 10.258575 13  1     1     1
6 13.430130  9  0     1     0
```

If I want to impute `m` times to find the average estimates for `x1` and `x2`, in what idea to create multiple `df$yimp1...df$yimpm`. Why are not these estimates same in different runs? Could someone give an example for `m=3`?

Comment: I don't think that you're supposed to average imputed values.

Comment: Yes, I understand. In the example, the first set of estimates is coef(fit). I wondering how to get the second, third,...set of estimates for m times.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure it myself from the original Rubin paper, the rest imputations are conducted up the new draw $\beta$s according to the fitted $\hat{\beta}$ and its variance and covariance matrix.

In this case,

```
newbeta=coef(fit)+chol(vcov(fit))*rnorm(dim(coef(fit))[1])
```

Then the newbeta are used to predict imp2 etc.